# Can't set correct date using jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

this is my problem i've this :

```
<script>$(function() {$( "#dataInizioBook" ).datepicker();});</script>
<input type="text" id="dataInizioBook" value="01/01/2013"/>
```

The datepicker will show another date selected when i click the input text.

Thank's for the help.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uSSs2/. Do you have other code that might be causing issues? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in case your browser is configured to use different culture:

```
$(function() {$( "#dataInizioBook" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });});
```